# can't update state in solidity test blockchain

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js, truffle, ganache

I'm trying to connect [this example](https://solidity-by-example.org/first-app/) to a frontend using web3. I have it copied exactly in my truffle project `/contracts` folder.

Compilation and migration are both successful.  (I have truffle configured to deploy on my ganache test network, and when I run `truffle migrate`, I see that the first account is debited ether).

I've created a Vue app to interact with the contract via web3.  Here's what my component looks like:

```
<template>
<div class="hello">
    <button @click="inc">increment</button>
    <button @click="dec">decrement</button>
    <button @click="get">get</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
const Web3 = require("web3");

const addr = '0xfbe7892aF06c7ecfbd83a0aD7F1D0a228d90Bf89'

const abi = [
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "count",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function",
        "constant": true
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "get",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function",
        "constant": true
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "inc",
        "outputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "dec",
        "outputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    }
]

export default {
    name: 'HelloWorld',
    data () {
        return {
            web3: null,
            contract: null,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        get(){
            self.contract.methods.get().call(function(err, result){
                console.log(result)
            })            
        },
        inc(){
            self.contract.methods.inc().call(function(err, result){
                console.log(result)
            })            
        },
        dec(){
            self.contract.methods.dec().call(function(err, result){
                console.log(result)
            })            
        },
    },
    created () {
        self.web3 = new Web3('http://localhost:7545')
        self.contract = new self.web3.eth.Contract(abi, addr)        
    }
}
</script>
```

When I run `inc`, no err is thrown.  I expect to see that value increment when I run `get`, but it always outputs `0` - apparently `inc` doesn't update the state.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a difference between a [call](https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API#eth_call) (read-only, gas-free) and a [transaction](https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API#eth_sendtransaction) (read-write, costs gas fees).

Since you want the `inc()` function to update the state, you need to [send()](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.5.2/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-send) a transaction instead of a call.

Your local web3 instance (usually in production) or the remote node (usually in development, e.g. using Ganache) needs to hold the private key to the `senderAddress` to be able to send the transaction.

```
self.contract.methods.inc().send({from: senderAddress}, function(err, result){
    console.log(result)
})
```